# Draw reCaptcha image from web page in ImageView

Tags: android, recaptcha

In my Android project i get web page with HttpGet and HttpClient that contains in their body captcha image from reCaptcha service. I want to show this image in ImageView in my application. So user can recognaize text from picture, enter them into EditText and press "Send" button check the captcha. 
Ofcourse, i can do this manually. I can parse the first GET response, cut the link, do request to this link, again get new web page with picture from reCaptcha, parse this response, crate link to image, download bytes and than trasfrom them into Bitmap, but may be exists any ready solutions?

Comment: Google says: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/torrentleechdroid/ben/TorrentLeechDroid/reCaptcha.java.htm , but I guess you've tried that one already.

Comment: Yup, that's what the torrentleechdroid code appears to do - take a web page (HTML), use regexp to find the re-captcha code & return the image URL & other related goodies to you.